# Can not remember the name of an effect --- where should I ask?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a phenomenon in mind but can't remember the name. Without name or other keywords, I can google for the rest of my life. Where, in general, should I ask in such a case?

The concrete thing I can't remember the name of right now is the relativistic effect that alters classical gravitational orbits to lose energy so the orbiting objects will finally collide. (Each object "sees" the other at some point slightly behind the position where it would be in the classical case, so gravitational pull is not exactly perpendicular to the orbit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [notation/terminology policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/are-physics-related-notation-and-terminology-questions-on-topic), it would best asked in [the h-bar (i.e., physics chat room)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), rather than a question on the main page.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. How do I get to this side (other than to follow your link here)?

Comment: Click the "Stack Exchange" at the top of the page, ensure that Physics is the "Current Community," then select "chat" to the right of Physics.

Comment: Alternatively, click the link I gave, then save it as a bookmark ;)

Comment: I have a habit to lose my bookmarks while trying *things* with my computer ;-( Did I see this right that you magically beamed this question to the chat side already?

Comment: No, there's a script that the site runs that automatically posts new Meta.Physics questions into the chatroom.