# How to make the question about "the principle of optimization" not opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question in question: [Why isn't the principle of least action named as "the principle of optimization"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659436/41634)

I suppose that one solution is to define what optimization/optimal state/optimized state is. This brings to a new question: would asking "How is optimization/optimal state/optimized state defined in physics?" be opinion-based?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Names are determined historically by what sticks, and it seems that you are inherently asking for people's opinion on other possible names.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is asking about a name, and the names of ideas in physics are often historical accidents that have little significance. So in general it's a bit pointless asking why a particular name was chosen.

In this case the name *principle of least action* is actually appropriate - well almost. It's because for any trajectory we can calculate the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) and then we find the trajectory for which this value is least. Hence *least action*.

I say *almost* because we actually extremise the action i.e. it can be a minimum or a maximum, but as I said the names for things in physics are often not especially appropriate. Anyhow, *principle of extreme action* sounds like a gangster movie :-)

Comment: I understand why the name "principle of least action" is appropriate. Hmm, maybe I should ask "would it still correct to call the principle of least action the principle of optimization?"? Or "Does principle of least action imply optimization?"? Because optimization is, at least, a different concept to action

Comment: @Ooker "optimisation" is finding the "best" value for something, but "best" is a rather meaningless concept because it depends on what you consider to be "good". By contrast "least" is unambiguous.

Comment: I see. I wonder if saying that "the universe finds least action is good" is a stretch? Also, why not "the principle of minimal action"?

Comment: I doubt the universe cares what we think is "good" :-)

Comment: @Ooker, I think anchovies and pineapple are "good" on pizza, while other people think differently. That makes the word "good" opinion-based.  It's not allowed in questions on Stack Exchange sites.  ¶ Well, it is, but only when it is specifically defined first, as in "assuming a 'good' result is one that is within 5% of reality, would … produce a good result?" or as in "assuming 'goodness' means the square root of the absolute value of error, does method 'X' produce a better result than method 'Y'.

Comment: [To quote John Rennie](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-to-make-the-question-about-the-principle-of-optimization-not-opinion-based/13765?noredirect=1#comment52325_13765): > "optimisation" is finding the "best" value for something, but "best" is a rather meaningless concept because it depends on what you consider to be "good". By contrast "least" is unambiguous. <-- I didn't think about that. In retrospect the reason I didn't see why "optimisation" opinion-based was because I assumed that the least action was a "good" value already.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it can be asked on chat?